# awk to create new variables based on conditions of other columns

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, multiple-columns

I have a file `input.txt` (~100'000 lines) with this structure:

```
Z0        Z1        Z2
0.9746    0.0254    0.0000     
0.0032    0.0000    0.9433  
0.2464    0.5603    0.9008 
0.4034    0.4982    0.0069 
0.0072    0.9996    0.0472 
...       ...       ...
```

And I want to create a new file `output.txt` with an additional column named `SCORE` based on the following conditions:

- SCORE = 1 if: 0.17 ≤ Z0 ≤ 0.33 and 0.40 ≤ Z1 ≤ 0.60
- SCORE = 2 if: 0.40 ≤ Z0 ≤ 0.60 and 0.40 ≤ Z1 ≤ 0.60
- SCORE = 3 if: Z0 ≤ 0.05 and Z1 ≥ 0.95 and Z2 ≤ 0.05
- SCORE = 4 if: Z0 ≤ 0.05 and Z1 ≤ 0.05 and Z2 ≥ 0.95
- SCORE = 5 if the other 4 conditions did not apply.

`output.txt` would look like this:

```
Z0        Z1        Z3         SCORE
0.9746    0.0254    0.0000     5
0.0032    0.0000    0.9433     5
0.2464    0.5603    0.9008     1
0.4034    0.4982    0.0069     2
0.0072    0.9996    0.0472     3           
...       ...       ...
```

Here is what I tried:

```
awk 'NR==1{$4="SCORE";print;next} \
  0.17<=$1 && $1<=0.33 && 0.40<=$2 && $2<=0.60 {$4="1"} \
  0.40<=$1 && $1<=0.60 && 0.40<=$2 && $2<=0.60 {$4="2"} \
  $1<=0.05 && $2>=0.95 && $3<=0.05 {$4="3"} \
  $1<=0.05 && $2<=0.05 && $3>=0.95 {$4="4"} \
  *other* 1' input.txt > output.txt
```

However, something is wrong in the first 5 command lines and I don't know how to write the last condition (for score 5) in the last line.

Comment: Your output looks little buggy, please check it once(though I didn't fully see it) but on first sight it looks. Also you don't have S2 in your Input_file too, please correct them in your post too.

Comment: No need to quote numbers, no need for the backslashes.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the errors, I've corrected them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
NR==1{$4="SCORE";print;next}
0.17<$1  && $1<0.33  && 0.40<$2  && $2<0.60 {print $0, "1";next}
0.40<$1  && $1<0.60  && 0.40<$2  && $2<0.60 {print $0, "2";next}
$1<=0.05 && $2>=0.95 && $3<=0.05            {print $0, "3";next}
$1<=0.05 && $2<=0.05 && $3>=0.95            {print $0, "4";next}
{print $0, "5"}
```

(There probably is an error in line 2 of your output, as 0.9433 is less than 0.95)

Answer (score 1):

no need for backslashes and quoting the numbers...
Your conditions described and the code doesn't match (`<=` vs `<`).

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $0,"SCORE"; next} 
  {score=5}
  0.17<$1 && $1<0.33 && 0.40<$2 && $2<0.60 {score=1}
  0.40<$1 && $1<0.60 && 0.40<$2 && $2<0.60 {score=2}
  $1<=0.05 && $2>=0.95 && $3<=0.05         {score=3}
  $1<=0.05 && $2<=0.05 && $3>=0.95         {score=4}  
  {print $0,score}' file | column -t

Z0      Z1      Z3      SCORE
0.9746  0.0254  0.0000  5
0.0032  0.0000  0.9433  5
0.2464  0.5603  0.9008  1
0.4034  0.4982  0.0069  2
0.0072  0.9996  0.0472  3
```

also your second line expected score is wrong.

Or, perhaps merging same conditions

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $0,"SCORE"; next} 
  {score=5}
  0.40<$2 && $2<0.60 {if(0.17<$1 && $1<0.33)   score=1;
                      if(0.40<$1 && $1<0.60)   score=2}
  $1<=0.05           {if($2>=0.95 && $3<=0.05) score=3;
                      if($2<=0.05 && $3>=0.95) score=4}  
  {print $0,score}' file | column -t
```